# Resolving symbolic links and relative URLs

Tags: php, symlink

I have a symbolic link `/var/www/html/lib/` which points to `/var/www/application/lib/`.

In file `/var/www/application/lib/testing/imageMaker2/otherFile.php`, I have created a new file `/var/www/application/lib/testing/imageMaker2/images/test.png`.

Next, I wish `otherFile.php` to send the URL relative to the webserver document root to the client (i.e. `/lib/testing/imageMaker2/images/test.png`).

Without having prior knowledge of the symbolic link, how is this possible?

test.php

```
<?php
require_once('otherFile.php');
otherFile(__DIR__.'/images/'); //Or what ever upload directory is desired.
?
```

otherFile.php

```
<?php
function otherFile($path) {
    $path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    $image='test.png';
    echo('$path                               => '.$path."\n");
    echo('$image                              => '.$image."\n");
    echo('$path/$image                        => '.$path.'/'.$image."\n");
    echo('__DIR__                             => '.__DIR__."\n");
    echo('__FILE__                            => '.__FILE__."\n");
    echo('$_SERVER[SCRIPT_FILENAME]           => '.$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']."\n");
    echo('realpath($_SERVER[SCRIPT_FILENAME]) => '.realpath($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME'])."\n");
    echo('$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]                  => '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."\n");
    echo('$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]             => '.$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."\n");
    echo('$path_parts[dirname]                => '.$path_parts['dirname']."\n");
    echo('dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF])         => '.dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])."\n");
}
?>
```

OUTPUT

```
$path                               => /var/www/application/lib/testing/imageMaker2/images/
$image                              => test.png
$path/$image                        => /var/www/application/lib/testing/imageMaker2/images//test.png
__DIR__                             => /var/www/application/lib/testing/imageMaker2
__FILE__                            => /var/www/application/lib/testing/imageMaker2/otherFile.php
$_SERVER[SCRIPT_FILENAME]           => /var/www/html/lib/testing/imageMaker2/test.php
realpath($_SERVER[SCRIPT_FILENAME]) => /var/www/application/lib/testing/imageMaker2/test.php
$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]                  => /lib/testing/imageMaker2/test.php
$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]             => /var/www/html
$path_parts[dirname]                => /lib/testing/imageMaker2
dirname($_SERVER[PHP_SELF])         => /lib/testing/imageMaker2
```

Comment: Why don't you just concatenate the relative path with filename like `"/lib/testing/imageMaker2/". $filename;` ?

Comment: @JulioSoares  Relative path meaning `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']`?

Comment: If you want but then you will have to extract "test.php" first. I would define a constat instead. But you can even hardcode it.

Comment: Thanks Julio, but my intent was not to hardcode it or define a hardcoded constant.

Answer (score 0):

As per your comments...

```
$path_parts = pathinfo($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);

echo $path_parts['dirname'];
```

Then you just extract what you want.

Comment: `dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])` will do the same.  Still will need to do some manipulating using concat or str_replace...

Comment: but isn't the filename already in a variable?
what is that bad about `$path = dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . $filename;` for instance?

Comment: Yes, `$filename` is a variable and so is the path to where it is located.  I didn't originally do a good job showing that and edited the original post.

Comment: So why you don't do it?

Comment: Do what?  Edit the original post?  I did.  Within `otherFile($path)`, I need to comeup with `/lib/testing/imageMaker2/images/test.png` where $path is any valid public file path.

Comment: concatenate `dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) . $filename;` and show the result to the client for God's sake!!

Comment: `$path` is not necessarily coupled to `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])`.